# compare the values of two lists with scientific values in tcl and return the highest values in new list

Tags: list, tcl, list-comparison

I want to compare two list with scientific values, and store the highest values in new list.
let say,

```
set X_value [list 1.215647671415354e-7 1.1284486163276597e-6 0.00019818406144622713 2.9287846814440854e-7 2.0217831320223922e-7]

set Y_value [list 1.215647671415354e-7 1.1284486163276597e-6 4.538622670224868e-5 4.4706815970130265e-5 8.492852430208586e-6 6.077577836549608e-6 3.1041158763400745e-6 0.00015045881445985287 4.1016753016265284e-7 1.165599314845167e-6 1.8736355968940188e-6 2.9444883693940938e-5 2.5420340534765273e-5 2.0819682049477706e-6 9.529731869406532e-6 8.549810104341304e-7 1.558014082547743e-5 8.079621693468653e-6 4.868444739258848e-5 0.0001646481396164745]
```

Need to compare each values of X_value with Y_value, and add the higher values of Y_value to a new list.As I was new to TCL, i find difficulty in implementing this.

Comment: How do you mean? Do you mean that you want to get the larger value at a particular index? What happens when the two lists are of a different length, as in your example?

Comment: not in particular index, i want to compare elements of Y_value with X_value,if Y_value is greater than X_value, then add it in new list.take Y_value and compare it with X_value.

Comment: It's just that I'm trying to understand exactly what you're trying to do. I can easily write something that _might_ be what you want, but might also be utterly wrong. Right now, I can see that the first two items in the lists are the same, and the following ones are not, but I don't know what signficance that has. ***What results do you want to get with your sample input data?***

Comment: the first two items were  extracted extracted from Y_value and added in X_Value, similarly the other 3 values in X_Value also extracted from other curves. The  EXpected output is [0.0001646481396164745 ] or [1.64582E-04]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do *pairwise* comparisons, accumulating a new list of values from `X_Value` that are greater than the *corresponding* values from `Y_Value`, and stopping once *either* list is exhausted:

```
proc pick_excess {X_list Y_list} {
    set result {}
    foreach x $X_list y $Y_list {
        if {($x ne "") && ($y ne "") && ($x > $y)} {
            lappend result $x
        }
    }
    return $result
}
puts [pick_excess $X_Value $Y_Value]
```

or maybe this instead (which avoids string comparisons):

```
proc pick_excess {X_list Y_list} {
    set limit [expr {min([llength $X_list], [llength $Y_list]) - 1}]
    return [lmap x [lrange $X_list 0 $limit] y [lrange $Y_list 0 $limit] {
        string cat [expr {$x <= $y ? continue : $x}]
    }]
}
puts [pick_excess $X_Value $Y_Value]
```

**BE AWARE!** You're comparing (double precision) floating point numbers, and it is usually a very good idea to think carefully about when floating point numbers should be thought of as equal as two methods of producing “the same” value may actually yield values that vary by the least significant bit (or more, if one of the the algorithms isn't great). Be careful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But using the first method I'm getting different output. the highest value in Y_value is [0.0001646481396164745 ] or [1.64582E-04],but I'm getting [4.4706815970130265e-5 8.492852430208586e-6].